# Why do some launch vehicle stages have checkerboard patterns?

Tags: rockets

Although this seems to apply to older launch vehicles, many of them have checkerboard patterns on the stages and/or interstages. Is it cosmetic or functional? If functional, then what is the purpose? Fiduciary marking for camera tracking? Thermal control? Some kind of colour scheme for construction and assembly purposes?

Comment: Someone beat you on this one.

Comment: Ah yes, I searched for "checkerboard" before asking but should have added "pattern". Thanks!

Comment: I found it by searching for 'markings'.